# Impact of GeoTrust/Symantec distrust certs (9/13)

Tags: ssl-certificate

So Chrome 70 is going to distrust these SSL certificates beginning 9/13. Not that we aren't working towards replacing those that need it, but what about other browsers? Will they still trust after 9/13 (IE, Firefox, Etc...). I couldn't find an article that addresses this specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Safari and Firefox are distrusting them, as well (with slightly different dates). I can't find indication either way on Internet Explorer, but Chrome alone is more than half of desktop users, not to mention virtually all mobile users being on iOS or Android. This is not something to slow-walk - **if you have Symantec certs, replace them now**.

- https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2018/03/12/distrust-symantec-tls-certificates/
- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208860

Comment: From what I am seeing the real drop-dead date is 10/16/18 since Chrome 70 is due to final release on that date.  I am replacing prior to 9/13 anyhow.  Thanks for the great info!

Answer (score 1):

[Google](https://security.googleblog.com/2018/03/distrust-of-symantec-pki-immediate.html) (Chrome, probably ChromeOS and Android in general), [Mozilla](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2018/03/12/distrust-symantec-tls-certificates/) (Firefox) and [Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208860) (Safari, probably MacOS and iOS in general) have all stated they will distrust Symantec certificates.

Google and Mozilla adopted matching timelines (roughly, the release dates for the relevant product versions aren't perfectly aligned) for the final step of this plan, where they fully distrust all Symantec certs (regardless the date it was issued). The release dates appear to be 2018-10-16 (Chrome 70) and 2018-10-23 (Firefox 63) respectively.
Apple have not announced the actual date for when they will complete that same step, only that they will do it (and have already completed a date-based initial step similar to what Google and Mozilla did earlier).

The elephant in the room would appear to be Microsoft. I do not believe they have made any announcement regarding distrusting Symantec certs at all.

Comment: Thanks I'd accept yours as solution but @ceejayoz was first.  Good info anyhow.  Thanks!

Comment: @JonGlazer Best trumps first - if this one answered your question *better*, by all means accept it. My feelings won't be hurt! :-)